# Something interesting about Pi, but something seems amiss

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I saw something interesting about text-analysis - bigrams - in [Basic Text Analysis in Mathematica](http://williamjturkel.net/2012/11/19/basic-text-analysis-in-mathematica/)

I wondered how the bigrams of Pi's digits might appear. As expected, take enough terms and every integer in the range 0-9 has been followed by every other number (including itself).

Here's my code -- I'm sure it can be improved, but that's my second question:

```
t = Table[
   edgeList = Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &,
     Partition[First[RealDigits[N[π, J]]], 2, 1]];
   g = Graph[Union[edgeList], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
   am = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
   Total[am, 2], {J, 2, 600}
   ];
ListLinePlot[t]
t
```

The idea here is that the total of the adjacency matrix of the bigram graph tells you when you've looked at enough of Pi's digits for every single-digit integer to have been followed by every single digit integer.

The problem I have found in the result (looking at `ListLinePlot[t]`, and then inspecting the sequence of `Total[AdjMat, 2]`) *is that the plot isn't monotonic*. I have to think that there's something I've done/omitted in the code, but no matter how hard I look I can't see it.

Can anyone see the problem that causes incorrectness of results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change one line of your code :

```
Partition[IntegerDigits@IntegerPart@(Pi*10^(J - 1)), 2, 1]
```

You could also use:

```
First[RealDigits[N[Pi, J+1], 10, J]]
```

As an aside, here's how I'd do it...

```
trend = With[{pidi = Partition[First@RealDigits[N[Pi, 1000]], 2, 1], 
               dummy = Transpose@{Range[0, 9]}}, 
   Table[Length /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ GatherBy[Join[dummy, pidi[[;; j - 1]]], First],
          {j, 2, 600}] - 1];

Column[{ListLinePlot[Total /@ trend, ImageSize -> 400],
        ListLinePlot[Count[#, 10] & /@ trend, ImageSize -> 400],
        ListLinePlot[Transpose@trend, PlotLegends -> Range[0, 9], 
                     PlotStyle -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

Giving your results, the count of how many digits have reached their fill, and the trends for the individual digits... n.b.: The plots are from 10-650, I later changed the code to match your index start/end.

If you're looking to extend this to bigger searches, you'll probably want to use something more efficent (the above is more efficient than yours, but for huge searches it's not optimal). *Mathematica* has *very* efficient string mechanisms, and often search problems of this sort can be done much more efficiently using them.

Here's an example, extending the search to trigrams. Completes in milliseconds on a ratty old netbook:

```
s = IntegerString[IntegerPart[Pi*10^10000]];

sp = Sort /@ 
    Partition[StringPosition[s, StringTake["00" <> ToString@#, -3], 1] & /@ 
                              Range[0, 999], 100][[All, All, 1, -1]]; 

ListPlot[Table[Tr[UnitStep[z - Flatten@sp]], {z, 3, 10000}], ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks - I see your code is more elegant than mine though I can't see why one would Join static 'dummy' to digits of Pi. I also cannot understand the error in my original code (I see you advised "replace the first line", but that doesn't explain what my error is.

Comment: @Paul_A: Sorry, figured it would be evident from the change. Do RealDigits[N[Pi, 5]], then RealDigits[N[Pi, 6]]. Look at the fifth digit in both. Rounding was your nemesis. As far as your code and "elegant", I disagree with your comment: I find your approach *quite* elegant, the use of Adj. Mat. sums clever. It's just not particularly *efficient* or quite as extension-friendly. As for the dummy join: gather/tally/et. al "index" in the order of "new" items seen. So this allows me to force 0,1,2... order. Otherwise, you'd have to figure out data order post hoc. Cleaner, IMO.

Comment: Dang! I should have seen that - something was nagging at me and at your mention of 'rounding' it hit home. Thanks also for the explanation of your rationale.